# Some requests in postman batch take longer than usual

Tags: post, iis, request, postman, http-post

I have a request in a Postman request batch that takes longer than usual. Here is the request as a standalone request:
[image: standalone request]

As you can see it takes about 300ms on average.

Here is that same request in a batch of requests:
[image: request in batch]

In the batch, 8 requests are sent out 5 times. 3/5 iterations all the requests are handled in the expected 300ms avg. but in 2/5 of the iterations that one request takes around 4000-10000ms. I thought it might be a problem with the IIS App pool, but even if I process that request first, it still takes longer than it should take. Any idea as to what could be going on? Note this running on a VM, not sure if that makes a difference, but here is the CPU info:
CPU

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6226R CPU @ 2.90GHz

Maximum speed:  2,89 GHz
Sockets:    8
Virtual processors: 8
Virtual machine:    Yes
L1 cache:   N/A

Utilization 1%
Speed   2,89 GHz
Up time 0:04:52:24
Processes   63
Threads 1124
Handles 27599
```

Comment: To find out the exact reason, you should first turn on the log feature of IIS. Use [IIS Log] + [Failed Request Tracing Log] to find out where the request gets a slowness. You can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis . You should define the failure as 'Time taken (in seconds)' with a proper time limitation.

Comment: @XinFang Okay thank you! Ill try that out and try to see if anything stands out!